# How do I get the last merge from develop into master in Git?

Tags: git, merge, git-log

In order to automate my CI, I need to get the info of the last merge executed from the **develop** branch into the **master** branch (or more generically, from a given source branch to a given destination branch).
I tried with

```
git log --oneline --merges  master -20
```

but this get me a list of all the last 20 merges into **master**, without differentiating by source branch (leaving me with the cumbersome task to parse and infer the source branch from the comment).
Is there a clean and robust way to filter by source branch **directly from the command line** ?

Note: I **do not** need for suggestions related to CI or branch-management best practices. We internally use the GitFlow workflow (https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow), so everything repository/CI-related is already in perfect order (methodologically speaking). I just need for a **very specific** answer to a **very specific** question, thanks !

Comment: Your question is unclear. Provide an example history (possibly with mulitple branches) and the expected output.

Comment: @j6t sorry, but I don't understand your perplexities. Which part of the sentence "last merge executed from the **develop** branch into the **master** branch" is unclear or can be misunderstood ?

Comment: Sorry, after re-reading, it is clear now.

Comment: You can kinda do this, but this is difficult and error prone. Why do you need this to automate your CI? It's likely there's a better approach.

Comment: @Schwern It's a very complex scenario inside a multi-project CI workflow... it's a "bit" difficult to explain (and AFAIK not very usefull to let you understand this specific question). Do you have a suggestion to offer ? I can accept also a hint :)

Comment: @NinjaCross Best practice is all development happens in one branch per issue known as "feature branches". Feature branches must pass CI before they're allowed to be merged into master. After a feature branch is merged it is deleted. master must pass CI before it is released to staging. master is always kept in a known good state. There is no separate "develop" branch. There are no long running branches (except master). Branches are never merged more than once.

Comment: @Schwern sorry, I don't mean to be rude, but you are far off-topic. I'm well aware of all best practices related to CI and branches management (we use the "GitFlow" methodology workflow https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow). Do you have a pertinent and in-topic suggestion for my question ?

Comment: @NinjaCross Git merges don't remember what branches they merged from or to. You can kinda fake it. I'm hoping to steer you away from a complex and error prone procedure to a simpler and more robust one.

Comment: @Schwern thank you anyway for your effort

Comment: Will it be good solution to provide tag on each merge of development to master and using commit id from last tag and you can get info through that commit id ?? @NinjaCross

Comment: @abby37 I cannot enforce any kind of tagging rule, so any strategy based on tags would be weak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to filter by source branch directly from the command line?

No. Branches in Git are just labels. Merges don't remember what branch they were merged to nor from, they only remember their parent commits and commit messages. Once merged both histories are equally part of the branch.

These are both different views of the same repository.

```
      < C <-- D <---- I [develop]
     /         \     /
A < B < E < F < G < H [master]

              <------ I [develop]
             /       /
A < B < C < D < G < H [master]
     \         /
      E <--- F
```

All commits except I are part of the `master` branch (ie. they can be reached from H). All commits are part of the `develop` branch (ie. they can be reached from I). Was G a merge from `develop` or from an unrelated branch? Topologically there is no way to tell.

Best you can do is hope try to deduce the information from the merge commit message and history. If your merge commit messages are consistent, you might be able to get away with something like this, but it is fragile.

```
git log --oneline --merges <destination> | grep "Merge branch '<source>'"
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. That's exactly the strategy I was hoping to avoid (because as you correctly stated, it's fragile). I hoped for a better and more reliable solution. I'll wait for some more contributes from the community. If nobody has a better suggestion, I'll mark your answer as accepted. Thanks.

Comment: Can't you simply iterate over all merge commits in `master` and check for each whether the second parent is a commit on `develop`?

Comment: I think you buried the lede there, `git log master --first-parent -1 --merges --grep "^Merge branch 'development'"` will almost certainly do it, the only time it fails is if they've customized their workflow, and people who do that don't need to ask this question.

Comment: @sschuberth How do you check whether the second parent was a commit on `develop`? Consider commit `G` in the example above.

Comment: I'm not familiar with git-flow, but I guess its workflow allows to merge `master` into `develop`, which is the underlying problem. My thinking was that it should be possible to look at the history of `develop` at the *time* of the merge commit in *master*, and then filter out the commits on `develop` that also were on `master` at that time. If the merge parent is in the remaining set of commits, that commit was only on `develop` at that time, and thus the merge originated from `develop`.

Comment: @jthill a grep on the comment would be a weak approach, considering that I cannot enforce any kind of rule related to comments and tags.

Comment: Of course you can, you can enforce any rules you want, that's what the pre-receive hook's for.

Comment: @sschuberth While that might work as a one-off with a human checking, I don't know that I'd trust commit times to be accurate and unaltered for an automated process. I'd be interested to see what you come up with in an answer.

Comment: @jthill The lede is "reconsider making this part of your process".

Comment: @jthill I didn't say that "it cannot be done". I said "I cannot enforce". I need a general solution, not a vertical one which can be applied only at server level with specific privileges

Comment: Your repositories are yours. You enforce any rules you want in repositories you administer.

Comment: Yes, I'm serious. Dictating what happens in a repo, "enforcing rules", is an administrative function. Is your question really "how do I usurp administrator privileges"?

Answer (score -2):

I recommended create a special log, the next gist have a awesome log to view diferents branches, user and the commit time ago

https://gist.github.com/gollum23/bbb115977677b60eea97

Comment: Can you elaborate ? How do I use this log to get the info of the last merge executed from the develop branch into the master branch ?

Comment: This is the output of superlog

Comment: It's indeed visually nice, but *specifically* talking about the *current question*, I sincerely don't see how it can be more usefull than the plain, basic log.