# How to auto increment tags based in last branch merged name?

Tags: git, devops, release, git-merge, git-tag

We are trying to make an automation, when some branch is merged in master automatically creates a new tag version. 
Our unique rule for this is: 
if the branch merged in master comes from feature the MINOR level will be increased else PATCH level will be increased.

I already have this script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

#latest version
VERSION=`git describe --abbrev=0 --tags`

# needs some if to determine if will increase minor or patch ...
VERSION_BITS=(${VERSION//./ })
VNUM1=${VERSION_BITS[0]}
VNUM2=${VERSION_BITS[1]}
VNUM3=${VERSION_BITS[2]}
VNUM3=$((VNUM3+1))

NEW_TAG="test$VNUM1.$VNUM2.$VNUM3"

echo "Updating $VERSION to $NEW_TAG"

GIT_COMMIT=`git rev-parse HEAD`
NEEDS_TAG=`git describe --contains $GIT_COMMIT 2>/dev/null`

if [ -z "$NEEDS_TAG" ]; then
    git tag $NEW_TAG
    echo "Tagged with $NEW_TAG"
    git push --tags
else
    echo "Already a tag on this commit"
fi
```

But I can not figure out how to implement the rule.

For example:

**feature scenario**

```
last tag v1.0.0
last branch merged in master feature/my-amazing-feature
new tag v1.1.0
```

**hotfix scenario**

```
last tag v1.1.0
last branch merged in master hotfix/missing-some-element
new tag v1.1.1
```

Comment: You might be interested in the answers and comments to [How do I get the last merge from develop into master in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58388374/how-do-i-get-the-last-merge-from-develop-into-master-in-git/58389933#58389933). tl;dr: You can't reliably determine the branches of a merge commit after the fact. This should instead be done as part of a larger integration process, like a pull or merge request. And consider if it's valuable to your users to have every hotfix or feature merge increment the version even if never "released".

Answer (score 0):

Try [scm4j-releaser](https://github.com/scm4j/scm4j-releaser) as an alternative. It automates the whole git-flow